# Store outputs in workspace without printing out in matlab command window

Tags: matlab

I want to store my outputs of a function in Matlab so that I can use the outputs without running the whole function again.

Comment: So, assign the outputs to variables. How are you calling your function?

Comment: I called [E] = band_matrix(n), where E is the eigenvalue of my banded matrix, and n is the size of the matrix

Comment: And the results were not stored in `E`?

Comment: The results were stored, but I don't want the results to be printed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is a quite easy!
Just add an semicolon after function calling (from [Matlab Documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/symbol-reference.html#bsgigzp-46))

> Output Suppression
>
> When placed at the end of a command, the semicolon tells MATLAB not to
>   display any output from that command.

for example:

```
function [E] = myfun(n)
E = n;
end
```

**your version:**

```
x = myfun(5)
```

result:

```
x =  5
```

**new version:**

```
x = myfun(5);
```

result: empty command window.

Comment: You are welcome! If it was helpful to you can you accept it as an right answer?